# How to change or rase a PIN to access a Windows computer with PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-activedirectory

I have a group of computers logged in with AzureAD users, normally they will set a pin for easy access. The thing is that when somebody leaves the company they can still access the computer local resources with this PIN, even if I already blocked them out in the Microsoft 365 admin panel.

I need to do this on the moment somebody leaves the company, so I normally run PowerShell scripts via RMM.

Is there a command to change or erase the PIN of a user?

Comment: "Is there a command to change or erase the PIN of a user?" - Have you tried disabling the ability to set a pin through the Group Policy then reenable it?

Comment: I don’t see how anything you do could work if locking the account apparently is not enough. Except of course simply confiscating the computer.

Answer (score 0):

The below PowerShell script to disable and delete the existing PIN
was found in the post
[How to Disable Pin Requirements When Joining Windows 10 PC to Azure AD and Using Office365 Business Premium](https://www.slashadmin.co.uk/how-to-disable-pin-requirements-when-joining-windows-10-pc-to-azure-ad-and-using-office365-business-premium/):

```
#Disable pin requirement
$path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft"
$key = "PassportForWork"
$name = "Enabled"
$value = "0"

New-Item -Path $path -Name $key –Force

New-ItemProperty -Path $path\$key -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force

#Delete existing pins
$passportFolder = "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc"

if(Test-Path -Path $passportFolder)
{
Takeown /f $passportFolder /r /d "Y"
ICACLS $passportFolder /reset /T /C /L /Q

Remove-Item –path $passportFolder –recurse -force
}
```